# ImageFailed event did not work in long list selector - WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using long list selector. I want to show default image when image is not found.

for that I am  having ImageFailed event. When I use this event in list box it worked fine.

BuT in long list selector it's not working.

May I know what mistake I did??

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding ListImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,2,0,0" ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ListFullName}" Width="200" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ListBio}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Foreground="Black" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="ExtraLight" FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Image Failed event in CS:-

```
private void Image_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorException.Message);
        Image Img = (Image)sender;
        Img.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/Test;component/Images/Head@2x.png", UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

This is my code. Please refer this and let me know what mistake I did?? 
And also I have tried FallBackValue. It is also Not working..
Is there any other way to load the default image if the image not found??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to place default `Image` below the your current one. This image will disappear after your image has been loaded and displayed

Comment: Hi.. Thank you for reply.. Where i do this process. I can not give in the source. I can give binding or direct image path. How to give both in same sorce??

Comment: <Grid><Image Source="default.png"/><Image Source={Binding ...}/></Grid>